# You must supply options input to rollup (vite)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite

when make npm run build show this error, i use laravel 10.0.3, and vite 9.0.1.
this error just show vite version 9, but when use vite version 8, all this is stable and run.
any solution for this problem,
thanks

The problem is that I can't read the full path filename, it returns an empty array

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import glob from 'glob'

let paths = [];
let output = [];
let publicPath = 'public/build'
glob('Modules/*/Resources/assets/js/**/*.js', function (err, files) {
    if (files.length > 0) {
        for (let k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
            let assetFilePath = files[k];
            paths.push(assetFilePath)
            let outputPath = assetFilePath.split('/Resources/')
            output.push(outputPath[1])
        }
    }
})

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: paths,
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        outDir: publicPath
    }
});
```

```html
@vite('Modules/Base/Resources/assets/js/base/base.js')
```